# using ccavenue payment gateway in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, namespaces, ccavenue

I'm using CakePHP 3.2. I have to integrate CCAvenue Payment gateway to my website.

I'm using https://github.com/kishanio/CCAvenue-PHP-Library library to integrate CCAvenue in my website.

But installing it via composer is not working

```
composer require kishanio/ccavenue
```

So, I downloaded and extract all files to

```
/vendor/CCAvenue-PHP-Library-master
```

path to `Payment.php`

```
/vendor/CCAvenue-PHP-Library-master/src/Payment.php
```

And in **controller**, I'm doing like

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;
require_once(ROOT.'/vendor/CCAvenue-PHP-Library-master/src/Payment.php');

use Kishanio\CCAvenue\Payment as CCAvenueClient;
class OrdersController extends AppController
{
    public function paymentViaPaymentGateway($invoice = null)
    {

          $payble_amount = 500;

          $ccavenue = new CCAvenueClient('key', 'id', 'redirect');

          // set details
          $ccavenue->setAmount($payble_amount);
          $ccavenue->setOrderId($invoice);
          $ccavenue->setBillingName($getOrder->user_address->name);
          $ccavenue->setBillingAddress($getOrder->user_address->line_1);
          $ccavenue->setBillingCity($getOrder->user_address->city);
          $ccavenue->setBillingZip($getOrder->user_address->postal);
          $ccavenue->setBillingState($getOrder->user_address->state);
          $ccavenue->setBillingCountry('India');
          $ccavenue->setBillingEmail($this->Auth->user('email'));
          $ccavenue->setBillingTel($this->Auth->user('mobile'));
          $ccavenue->setBillingNotes($invoice);

          // copy all the billing details to shipping details
          $ccavenue->billingSameAsShipping();

          // get encrypted data to be passed
          $data = $ccavenue->getEncryptedData();

          // merchant id to be passed along the param
          $merchant = $ccavenue->getMerchantId();

          $this->set('data', $data);
          $this->set('merchant', $merchant);
    }
}
```

**`Utils.php`** is located in same directory as `Payment.php`
and Payment.php contains

```
namespace Kishanio\CCAvenue;

use Kishanio\CCAvenue\Utils;
```

and **`Utils.php`** contains

```
namespace Kishanio\CCAvenue;

use Kishanio\CCAvenue\Payment;
```

**But, this gives error as**

> Fatal error: Class 'Kishanio\CCAvenue\Utils' not found in
>   /path_to/vendor/CCAvenue-PHP-Library-master/src/Payment.php on line
>   243

content of Payment.php where error is pointing.

```
public function getEncryptedData() {
  $utils = new Utils( $this );           // line 243
  $merchant_data = $this->getMerchantData( $utils->getChecksum() );
  return $utils->encrypt($merchant_data,$this->getWorkingKey());
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: I had to get it resolved one year back and do not remember what exactly I had done to solve it. If you are facing any issue, do post a separate question or add little more info in your comment, so that I could help you in a better way.

Comment: In my case the PagesController is unable to find the CCAvenueClient class. The issue seems almost similar. All I can assume is the missing of any single line of code which the actual owner of this repository has missed to mention. Let's see if you get any idea or suggest something otherwise I would keep trying other alternates.

Comment: you might be missing `use namespace` line which includes the class.

Comment: create a separate question with code snippet you are using and share the link to question.

Comment: No, that namespace declaration is all good. Anyways, I think I shall post my question separately. Thanks anyways